# JMeter Once Only Controller at the end

Tags: jmeter

I would like to perform a certain action per thread, so, I assume that tearDown Thread Group will not work.

Is there any alternative to run Once Only Controller only if it is the last iteration of a thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) to your Test Plan.
2. Use the following Expression as the If Controller's Condition (assumes [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)):

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty('LoopController.loops').toString() as int == (vars.get('__jm__Thread Group__idx') as int) + 1,)}
   ```
3. Put [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(s) you would like to execute at the end as a child(ren) of the If Controller

   [image: JMeter Execute After All]

Comment: @uru917 did this work for you? I get the below error from the if statement...javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instea

Comment: It worked for me. Don't forget to replace "Thread Group" string in the example by the name of your actual thread group. For example if the thread goup is called dummy it would be : "get('__jm__dummy__idx') as int)" @simon-n

Answer (score 2):

Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and check the following condition that current iteration is last. For example if therer are 10 iterations (loop count):

```
 ${__groovy(10 == vars.getIteration())}
```

If you have a variable holding number of iteration, check against variable as `myIteration`

```
 ${__groovy(vars.get("myIteration").toInteger() == vars.getIteration())}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that your solution works, but I would like to be able to get the number of iterations too, in order to do not update the if condition when the iterations are updated.

Comment: @uru917 How can the iteration updated?if you have a variable, check against variable as `${__groovy(vars.get("myIteration").toInteger()  == vars.getIteration())}`

Comment: Yes, the point is that I was wondering whether it was possible to obtain the number of Thread Group iterations, without using a variable. But that is another question. Thanks.