# How to add a delay in jmeter while running the same thread in loop using flowAction Control so that there is no delay after last loop

Tags: loops, jmeter, httprequest, threadgroup

[image]I have the following scenario:

```
Thread Group
-HTTP Request1
-HTTP Request2
-HTTP Request3
-HTTP Request4
-HTTP Request5
-HTTP Request6
-HTTP Request7
-HTTP Request8
-HTTP Request9
-HTTP Request10
```

I have the following condition, I need to execute all the 10 HTTP requests with loop count=30 set in thread group configuration.

How do i set up a delay of 25 seconds after each loop? i.e. after every loop executes there is a delay of 25 seconds. However, i don't want there to be a delay between the http requests only after the loops.
Also , i dont want there to be a delay of 25 seconds after the last loop. How do i achieve that?
Please help me out with the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) at the end of the test for pausing exact time before next loop

> it allows pauses to be included without needing to generate a sample. For variable delays, set the pause time to zero, and add a Timer as a child.

Comment: I did but it does not help.  Also I need a constant delay of 25 seconds how do i achieve that?

Comment: @radhika 25000 (ms) in Duration

Comment: hi yes . I dont want it to have a delay after the last loop is over i.e. after 30th loop. it is giving me delay for that as well. How do i achieve that?

Comment: @radhika see how to find last loop in
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023824/jmeter-once-only-controller-at-the-end

Answer (score 0):

You can kill 2 birds with 1 stone by switching to [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)

1. Add Constant Timer as a child of the first request
2. Configure it for fixed delay of `25000` milliseconds

   [image]

As Timers are being executed **before** requests - it will not be executed after the last loop.

---

If you don't want it to "sleep" before the first request during the first iteration - go for [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer), the code would be as simple as:

```
if (vars.getIteration() > 1) {
    return 25000
}
```

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

Comment: what does return 5000 here refer to as?

Comment: apologies, it was a typo, should be `25000`, it means that the timer will introduce 25 seconds delay for all iterations starting from 2nd